# Admob ad Error code : 0. Everithyng is updated and carefully programmed set it's not showing ads

Tags: android, admob

Here are my error codes:

```
07-31 13:37:47.413 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
07-31 13:37:47.522 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
07-31 13:37:47.530 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
07-31 13:37:47.544 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-31 13:37:47.620 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-31 13:37:47.810 31965-31977/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/IPCThreadState: [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x63a2fa50
07-31 13:37:53.071 31965-31978/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/IPCThreadState: [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x63a34d80
07-31 13:37:58.169 31965-31977/corvusbyte.neverboredlite W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
07-31 13:37:58.171 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
07-31 13:38:03.175 31965-31978/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/IPCThreadState: [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x64331428
07-31 13:39:18.091 31965-31965/corvusbyte.neverboredlite D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50000010 }, ordered=true, receiver=com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ac@4214bf40, IIntentReceiver=4214bf88
```

My xml (the ad part of it):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/main_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My java (part of it):

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "app_id");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView_main);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("85FB65B00143337DE5FE7492DF14F269")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="corvusbyte.neverboredlite">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="corvusbyte.neverboredlite.RESULTS"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my gradle files (parts of them):
module

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

My problem is that there are no ads showing. There is only a blank space on the top of my layout. I have the latest SDK tools, Google Play resources etc...
Please help me!

Comment: Instead of trying test add try live ads and see does it show or not, i have tested recently in my app it just runs fine on both real devices and emulator.

Comment: I use live ads. As far as I know... I use ad IDs of my admob account.

Comment: which id u r using? i also faced this issue and waited for 5, 10 mins thinking my net issue but then i used ca-app-pub-323434XXXdsds/4343Xdsw, 
the one under monetize tab under all apps the one you created with your app name

Comment: I use these https://postimg.org/image/rghaadew7/

Comment: how you have defined it in your res/values/strings 

<string name="ad_banner">ca-app-pub-610312RURWUYWURYU/75$^&^$@&$^</string>


like this?

Comment: <string name="main_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-325525xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx</string> With numbers, not "x"-es of course.

Comment: why this attribute of translateable? for making it hard to crack?  your ID will eventually be picked by hackers unless you wrap it under some hashing algos, so remove it then try.

Comment: I use my Allview P5 life with 4.4.2 android. It's rooted. I also tried on another phone. An Alview Viper something (unrooted). Not working :/

Comment: remove attribute of translateable then test

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: one thing i appreciate, you posted a well balanced question without any redundant code. (y) +1 for you. :)

Comment: Honestly it's not my first try... I got many minuses :/ But Thanks! :D

Comment: Hello Hyder! I know it's off topic but I'd like to tell you that via your help I just earned my first 0.06$ :D I'm so proud! Thanks for your help again! :)

Comment: Haha :) nice, so u uploaded your app on google play, tell me name i will download it too.

Comment: It's called Never Bored Lite :)

Comment: Please tell me what you think of it :)

Comment: kindly email me at mfaisalhyder@gmail.com i need to discuss something. app looks nice. :) some advices as well.!

Comment: I have sent an email. I hope I didn't make a typo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comments, you used attribute of `translatable= "false"`. Try to remove it and then run application. It will be possible to be accessed by code and will eventually ads will come up.