# AdMob android error : "Failed to load ad: 0"

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, adview

I'm getting the following error for my integration of AdMob to my android app.

```
03-23 03:53:48.374 19077-19077/io.sopo D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
03-23 03:53:48.375 19077-19077/io.sopo D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
03-23 03:53:48.417 19077-20268/io.sopo W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.sopo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.sopo-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
03-23 03:53:48.422 19077-20268/io.sopo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:12
03-23 03:53:48.422 19077-20268/io.sopo I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite, version >= 12
03-23 03:53:48.431 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-lg-flac
03-23 03:53:48.436 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/adpcm
03-23 03:53:48.438 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/g726
03-23 03:53:48.439 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/eac3
03-23 03:53:48.442 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
03-23 03:53:48.444 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/lg-wma-voice
03-23 03:53:48.446 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-lg-ms-wma
03-23 03:53:48.447 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/theora
03-23 03:53:48.450 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mjpg
03-23 03:53:48.477 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
03-23 03:53:48.480 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
03-23 03:53:48.503 19077-20268/io.sopo W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
03-23 03:53:48.511 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
03-23 03:53:48.513 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
03-23 03:53:48.515 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
03-23 03:53:48.516 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
03-23 03:53:48.526 19077-20268/io.sopo W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
03-23 03:53:48.543 19077-20268/io.sopo I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
03-23 03:53:48.549 19077-20268/io.sopo I/AudioManagerEx: AudioManagerEx created
03-23 03:53:48.550 19077-20268/io.sopo D/AudioManager: getMode name:io.sopo
03-23 03:53:48.595 19077-19077/io.sopo I/Ads: Starting ad request.
03-23 03:53:48.622 19077-20272/io.sopo I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 51.0.2704.81 (code 270408150)
03-23 03:53:48.730 19077-20272/io.sopo I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 5476-5478)
03-23 03:53:48.731 19077-20272/io.sopo I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.81", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.81"
03-23 03:53:49.566 19077-19088/io.sopo W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
03-23 03:53:49.569 19077-19077/io.sopo W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Here is my code (btw test device id has been edited to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX to hide it just in case):

```
NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder() .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();
adView.setVideoOptions(new VideoOptions.Builder()
        .setStartMuted(true)
        .build());
VideoController vc = adView.getVideoController();

vc.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
    public void onVideoEnd() {
        // Here apps can take action knowing video playback is finished
        // It's always a good idea to wait for playback to complete before
        // replacing or refreshing a native ad, for example.
        super.onVideoEnd();
    }
});
adView.loadAd(request);
```

XML code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="360x320"/>
```

However this same code works for **adUnitId = ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2177258514**

**build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    /* many other libraries over here */

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Anyone has any idea why this error occured? Please help.

Comment: Looks like a Google Play Services bug. Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: Did you actually use XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for your device id? You can learn how to use these [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38683747/2736849 see this question if it helps

Comment: @Shmuel - added

Comment: @ConnorT - No I did not, and I know how to use it, I've just hidden it because I was not sure if it needs to be hidden or not.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder - that didn't work.

Comment: Okay I will try to help you.

Comment: Try to Register your app once again to get new ID, it happens.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder - Register app where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138814/discussion-between-ketan-malhotra-and-muhammad-faisal-hyder).